# Change BottomDrawer's gesturesEnabled according to drawerState in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an `BottomDrawer` but i want that when `BottomDrawer` is closed the `gesturesEnabled` should be `false` else if its open then `gesturesEnabled` should be `true`

Here's the
[`code`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#BottomDrawer(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.BottomDrawerState,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)) 
I know its not my but same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val drawerState = rememberBottomDrawerState(BottomDrawerValue.Closed)
val gesturesEnabled = !drawerState.isClosed
Column {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Checkbox(gesturesEnabled, null)
        Text(text = if (gesturesEnabled) "Gestures Enabled" else "Gestures Disabled")
    }

    BottomDrawer(
        gesturesEnabled = gesturesEnabled,
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally).padding(top = 16.dp),
                onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.close() } },
                content = { Text("Close Drawer") }
            )
            LazyColumn {
                items(25) {
                    ListItem(
                        text = { Text("Item $it") },
                        icon = {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Favorite,
                                contentDescription = "Localized description"
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                val openText = if (gesturesEnabled) "▲▲▲ Pull up ▲▲▲" else "Click the button!"
                Text(text = if (drawerState.isClosed) openText else "▼▼▼ Drag down ▼▼▼")
                Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
                Button(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                    Text("Click to open")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```